# OpenCV 2.3.1 compiled with NDK6 crashes on Galaxy Tab 10.1

Tags: c++, opencv, android-ndk, galaxy-tab

I have the following problem:
The library `libopencv_java.so` compiled from OpenCV 2.3.1 with NDK6 works fine on Samsung Galaxy S, but not on Galaxy Tab.
Build setup:

-MacOS X

-NDK6

-build with neon

The library seems to fail on double->integer conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Galaxy Tab uses Nvidia Tegra 2 CPU.
Recently there was a bug fixed in NDK that generated invalid code for Tegra 2 processors related to floating point instructions. Here is the quote from NDK r7c [changelog](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html):

> This release of the NDK includes an important fix for Tegra2-based devices, and a few additional fixes and improvements:
>
> Important bug fixes:
>   Fixed GNU STL armeabi-v7a binaries to not crash on non-NEON devices. The files provided with NDK r7b were not configured properly, resulting in crashes on Tegra2-based devices and others when trying to use certain floating-point functions (e.g., cosf, sinf, expf).

So try recompiling OpenCV with at least NDK r7c.

Comment: Tried, build of 2.3.1 fails, but 2.4 builds.

Comment: You are saying 2.3.1 with NDK r7c (or NDK r8) also doesn't work on Galaxy Tab? Then try to isolate program in small source example and report the bug in Android NDK.

Comment: The issue mentioned in release notes is specific for NDK r7b only. Your binary crashes because of NEON enabled. Tegra2 CPU has VFPv3-d16 FPU while NEON requires VFPv3-d32 (they differs in number of floating-point registers). This means that code compiled with NEON support can not run on Tegra2 even if it does not use NEON instructions.

Comment: @AndreyKamaev Thank you! It explains everything. You should write it as an answer )